# Suppress the output of the RUN command in a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, echo

How can I suppress the output of the RUN command in a Dockerfile? In the code below, I'm attempting to redirect the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY to a file using the echo command. However, during image building, the Docker logs reveal the SSH PRIVATE KEY, which I'd like to avoid. Is there a way to silence the RUN command in a Dockerfile, or is there another solution to this issue?

```
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Build log

```
 => CACHED [app 10/19] RUN echo "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----0s9               0.0s
```

Comment: Since anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially extract files from it, your ssh key is already compromised if you do this.  Make sure to properly revoke the key anywhere you might have used it.  Do not pass credentials like this as Dockerfile `ARG` or otherwise supply them to the build process.

Comment: Try this `RUN bash -c 'echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed25519'` to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is to have the key in a file instead in the first place.

```
COPY privkey /home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed_25519
```

with `privkey` obviously in a local file in the directory where you run `docker build` et al.